# BeaverBuilder Wordpress Change Slideshow Caption Text Length

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to adjust the BeaverBuilder slideshow attribute to stop the captionTextLength from being truncated after the default 200 char.  I have identified the line within the Plugin/bb-plugin/js/fl-slideshow.js  file  line 8671 that controls these changes but am unsure of how to modify this as changing and uploading to the plugin folder directly will be overwritten when updates are pushed. It seems there needs to be a custom filter function added to the function.php file or maybe the custom module folder from supporting link below but don't really know.

Code snippet from the fl-slideshow.js file.

```
/**
         * The length of the caption to show. If greater than -1,
         * the text will be truncated and a read more link will
         * be displayed. If set to -1, the entire caption will be shown.
         *
         * @attribute captionTextLength
         * @type Number
         * @default 200
         */
        captionTextLength: {
            value: -1
        },
```

I have followed the directions here - https://docs.wpbeaverbuilder.com/beaver-builder/developer/custom-modules/cmdg-18-override-built-in-modules/ - to modify the module but there is nothing stating directions to aid in modifying the js files outside of the module directory.  Any help to point me in the right direction is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved.... Solution - Follow directions on beaverbuilder docs -  https://docs.wpbeaverbuilder.com/beaver-builder/developer/custom-modules/cmdg-18-override-built-in-modules  to create custom module

CMDG 18: Override built-in modules

Any of the built-in modules can be overridden within your theme by following the steps below.

```
Create a new folder in your theme's folder named fl-builder.
Create a new folder within your theme's fl-builder folder named modules.
Copy the entire module folder you wish to override from wp-content/plugins/bb-plugin/modules to your theme's fl-builder/modules folder.
```

Note

Copy the entire module folder and its contents, not just the files you want to override.

then treat  $this->add_js( 'fl-slideshow' ); as normal wp_enqueue_script function and overwrite the js file that is loaded by adding wp_register_script to load new js script in place of old one.

Reference link - https://docs.wpbeaverbuilder.com/beaver-builder/developer/custom-modules/cmdg-09-module-method-reference/